# How to post Advertisements from an IPhone Device which acts as iBeacon?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, uuid, ibeacon

i want to know some details about iBeacons. Couple of days back i created a sample  project where i turned my iOS Device into an iBeacon and i tracked down that iBeacon with   another device, i am also getting the proximity distance between my Device and the beacon.

So my question is Is it possible to post some advertisements from my device which acting as    iBeacon?

How to configure that? 
All i wanted to know is how the iBeacon Configuration done to send the data?
Some one please help me out

thankYou

Answer (score 0):

An iBeacon "advertisement" is just a constant transmission of a four part identifier that signifies a unique device.  It only contains four fields:

- **proximityUUID** (a 16 byte UUID usually expressed in the form 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
- **major** (a number from 0 to 65535)
- **minor** (a number from 0 to 65535)
- **power** (a number from 127 to -128)

That's it.  You can't make an iBeacon send any more data than that.  It doesn't matter if the device acting as an iBeacon is your phone, an iPad, a Mac computer, or a small battery-powered unit.

If you want to tie other data to an iBeacon, you have to do it through another channel, by some kind of lookup that matches the data up with the identifiers above.  You can do this with a static lookup table in your app, a web service, or a CoreBluetooth communication channel.  But you have to code that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response David, One more question is there any way to track multiple beacon identifiers with different minor values in one Store. How?

Comment: Easy.  If you want to see all beacons with a known UUID and major, but any value for minor, then use code like this.  Note that this region does not specify a minor value, so it matches all minor values.  CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"] major: 1 identifier:@"com.mycompany.myprogram"]; [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];

Comment: Currently on the Estimote the identifiers are specified by the manufacturer.
Can anyone please explain,how can i distinguish between mutiple estimote beacons placed near by region.
i ordered the Estimote beacon kit ,i thought i can configure each beacon with an Identifier and save those identifiers in my backend, so when ever i hit that region, i can send that identifier to my backend server, in response i can fetch the product detials regarding the product that placed in beacon region. Is it possible ?

Comment: My company Radius Networks has a service called ProximityKit that helps with this.  You do not even need your own back end, as we provide the cloud services.  You can tie an arbitrary iBeacon to a location and key/value pairs.  See www.proximitykit.com

Comment: Hey david thanks for the info, one more thing is it true that all the Estimote beacons comes with same UUID ,the estimote kit which i have received has three different UUID for 3 beacons, which i came to know after downloading and searched with BLExplr app.People started saying random things and its totally confusing me.Can you please make me understand.

Comment: I would use an app like BLExplr or Locate for iBeacon to find the identifiers of each of your beacons, then write them down on a sticker attached to each one.  If you really have 3 different Proximity UUIDs, you have to set up three different regions for monitoring/ranging.  But this is okay because you can still tie arbitrary key/value pairs to each one, using ProximityKit or your own scheme.  This way, the actual beacon identifiers won't really matter to you.